# The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation - Console Cloud Google

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-developer-api

I have a Google Dev Console process with Google Play Developer API is enabled and the project is linked to Google Play project. In Google Dev console project, created a service account (I'm an owner of the project). After that i create a json file key to authenticate. Tried to using google-api-client in PHP, Google Developer API Playground to send request to In-App-Purchase details of my apps but got error: "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation." I have already waited 28 hours. Details as below:

`GET Request https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}?access_token={access_token}`

Response

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [code] => 401
            [message] => *The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.*
            [errors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [message] => The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.
                            [domain] => androidpublisher
                            [reason] => permissionDenied
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

***List of permission i have given to google play developer console**[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com

Create a project (or select existing project)

Create a service account with role Pub/Sub Admin

Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library and search for "Google Play Android Developer API"

Enable that API

Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish

Go to Settings > Developer account > API Access

Link the project that you created

The service account will appear that you have created.

Grant access to it with Finance permission to the app in play console

If all above steps are correct then

Create and delete any temporary App product to force permission update.