# How to set on androidpublisher permission for Google Cloud Console (to manage in-app purchases in Google Play)?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-play, google-cloud-console

I work on in-app purchases in my app.

My backend software produces the error:
`<HttpError 401 when requesting https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/name.vporton.local_shops/purchases/products/credits_x1/tokens/XXX?alt=json returned "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.". Details: "[{'message': 'The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.', 'domain': 'androidpublisher', 'reason': 'permissionDenied'}]">`
when I try to use [this API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get).

Apparently, I need to give `androidpublisher` permission. But at https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/access-control there is nothing said about Android.

How to enable this permission?

I also already have:

- linked Google Play Console and my service account in Google Cloud Console
- assigned for my app permissions "View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses" and "Manage orders and subscriptions" in Google Play Console.

What do I do wrong?

Are "Consumer Procurement Order Administrator" and "Consumer Procurement Order Viewer" related to purchases in Android?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70290896/856090) advises to use "Pub/Sub Admin" role, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57100054/856090) advises "Owner" permission, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006689/856090) advises "Owner" or "Editor". Finally, they recommend to wait 24 hours after setting a permission. So which permission is right? (I don't want to try every one with waiting 24 hours after each try.)

Comment: I tried "Editor" and "Cloud Pub/Sub Service Agent" (without waiting 24 hours). Both don't work. What works?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?